# How do I create a directory so I can add multiple branches in it on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I don't use Git that often so bear with me, please. From my origin main branch repository in GitHub, I locally created a new branch (`feature-typescript`) using Git. I have staged and committed my files within the `feature-typescript` branch. I'm thinking there might be a lot of `feature-[name]` branches. So instead of having multiple branches with the same beginning name, I would like to put them in a directory to make my remote repository branch category more organized.

I have tried to create a branch directory named feature within my remote repository but I'm not able to figure out how. Is there a way I can create a new directory named feature to my GitHub repository using Git?

One last thing I want to add that I'm confused about. As I mentioned earlier, I have already staged and committed my `feature-typescript` branch. I tried to push it to my remote repository but I get this error:

```
fatal: The current branch feature/typescript has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature/typesccript
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There isn't anything like a branch directory. Simply name your branch 'feature/whatever' and use slashes instead of the minus. That's it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+current+branch+has+no+upstream+branch

Comment: As for the second question, simply use the command provided: `$ git push --set-upstream origin feature/typescript`.